# Is it possible to edit geographic data over the web in QGIS cloud or QGIS server?

Tags: editing, software-recommendations, qgis-server, qgis-cloud

I'm looking for something similar to the [ArcGis Server example](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/ags_editor/) but based on QGIS.

Could anybody tell me where I can get more information about functionalities like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the ability to overlay polygons on to a basemap you should look into [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/).  There is also a plugin that integrates geoserver management into QGIS.

Comment: Yes for instance. I want to digitize (polygone, line, point) over web. I'll check it out - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lizmap to create/edit/delete features via WFS with QGIS Server.

There is only a french documentation for this part though : [documentation](http://docs.3liz.com/fr/lizmap-plugin/features/edition.html)

Answer (score 0):

QGIS server and Lizmap can help you, and there are also offer for cloud services (e.g. http://www.gishosting.gter.it)